# PHP XML Parse (specifically for Tomboy/Gnote parsing to display/edit/add on Web UI)

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Am currently working on a new idea in order to get tomboy/gnote notes parsed via PHP and displayed on a web page in order to add/edit/view notes. With such a tool one could then possibly create an OwnCloud application therefore allowing for a complete solution with sincronization between all machines (with offline access) and include a Web UI. At a latter stage one could also develop an Android application.

I am somewhat new to PHP and XML and am therefore asking for some help.

**Here is an example XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note version="0.3" xmlns:link="http://beatniksoftware.com/tomboy/link" xmlns:size="http://beatniksoftware.com/tomboy/size" xmlns="http://beatniksoftware.com/tomboy">
<title>TEST Note</title><text xml:space="preserve">
<note-content version="0.1" xmlns:link="http://beatniksoftware.com/tomboy/link" xmlns:size="http://beatniksoftware.com/tomboy/size">TEST Note

Normal text
<size:huge>Huge text</size:huge>
<size:large>Large text</size:large>
<size:small>small text</size:small>
<bold>BOLD Text</bold>
<italic>Italic text</italic>
<strikethrough>Striked text</strikethrough>
<highlight>Highlight text</highlight>
<list><list-item dir="ltr">BulletA
<list><list-item dir="ltr">A1
</list-item><list-item dir="ltr">A2
<list><list-item dir="ltr">A2.1
<list><list-item dir="ltr">A2.1.1
<list><list-item dir="ltr">A2.1.1.1
<list><list-item dir="ltr">A2.1.1.1.1
</list-item></list></list-item></list></list-item><list-item dir="ltr">A2.1.2
</list-item></list></list-item><list-item dir="ltr">A2.2
</list-item></list></list-item><list-item dir="ltr">A3
</list-item></list></list-item><list-item dir="ltr">BulletB</list-item></list>

Normal text with space before

And again</note-content>
</text><last-change-date>2013-03-28T02:11:04.603700Z</last-change-date>
<last-metadata-change-date>2013-03-28T02:11:11.012211Z</last-metadata-change-date><create-date>2013-03-28T01:39:08.607520Z</create-date>
<cursor-position>124</cursor-position><selection-bound-position>124</selection-bound-position><width>496</width>
<height>458</height><x>0</x><y>0</y>
<tags><tag>system:notebook:test</tag></tags><open-on-startup>False</open-on-startup></note>
```

**Here is the code I currently have:**

```
<?php

$file = "example.note";

$xmlFile = file_get_contents($file) or die('Cant open note'); 
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlFile);
print_r($xml); 

?>
```

**And here is the output:**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( 
[version] => 0.3 ) 
[title] => TEST Note 
[text] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
[note-content] => TEST Note Normal text Normal text with space before And again ) 
[last-change-date] => 2013-03-28T02:11:04.603700Z 
[last-metadata-change-date] => 2013-03-28T02:11:11.012211Z 
[create-date] => 2013-03-28T01:39:08.607520Z 
[cursor-position] => 124 
[selection-bound-position] => 124 
[width] => 496 [height] => 458 
[x] => 0 [y] => 0 
[tags] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [tag] => system:notebook:test ) [open-on-startup] => False )
```

As you can see the "note content" isn't being entirely gathered and so I am reaching out to PHP guru's. How can I get the entire XML parsed in order to be able to then display it in normal HTML?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You really need to traverse the tree and go over every element in `<note-content>`. `print_r` is not really a means to get accurate output, nor is it it's function.

For something like this, I would actually highly recommend using `XMLReader`. It works quite nicely for loosely-formatted xml like this.

What you need to do in the end, is to traverse every element, and (probably) change tags such as `<bold>` to a html `<strong>` tag. Simplexml will suck for that purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Tomboy ships a XSLT file that converts tomboy notes to HTML - you can utility it without writing custom code:

https://git.gnome.org/browse/tomboy/tree/Tomboy/Addins/ExportToHtml/ExportToHtml.xsl